# Presenting a modal overlay ViewController removes the previous form the view hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

I'm trying to create a custom `ViewController` that will act as a `UIAlertViewController`, meaning that it will be displayed over the current `ViewController`, and will be dismissible after the user presses OK. Let's call this the `ErrorViewController`.

In all the case where I present this ErrorVC it works properly, overlaying the underlying ViewController. However, there is one particular ViewController that gets hidden whenever it presents the ErrorVC.

The code for presenting the ErrorVC is the following:

```
@objc static func showError(from presentingViewController: UIViewController,
                                title: String = kErrorSomethingWentWrong,
                                message: String? = kErrorTryAgainLater,
                                type: ErrorViewControllerType = .message) -> ErrorViewController {
        let errorViewController = UIStoryboard.main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ErrorViewController.identifier) as! ErrorViewController

        presentingViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext

        errorViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        errorViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve

        // Set the delegate of the dialog box to the parentViewController
        errorViewController.delegate = presentingViewController as? ErrorViewControllerDelegate

        errorViewController.errorTitle = title
        errorViewController.errorMessage = message ?? kErrorTryAgainLater
        errorViewController.type = type

        // Present the pop up viewController from the parentViewController
        presentingViewController.present(errorViewController, animated: true)

        return errorViewController
    }
```

I've tried setting `definesPrersentationContext` to `true` on my problematic `ViewController` with no luck. When debugging the view hierarchy, I can see that the problematic `ViewController` is removed from the hierarchy, and that's why it's not visible, while on all other `ViewControllers` the `presentingViewController` stays in the view hierarchy.

Any ideas on what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Something isn't making sense to me. Presenting a view controller means - visually - the presented view controller **is** on top or the presenter. Now, maybe you wish to somehow go back to a VC below the presenter on the "stack" - and I don't really know if presenting a VC visually above in terms of UI means the same thing as adding it to a VC stack. But why are you trying to remove the presenter before removing the presented?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this effect described here: https://medium.com/macoclock/how-to-create-and-use-custom-dialog-boxes-in-ios-4335be9dac34 A VC overlaying the previous VC, but it has a semi-transparent background, so that the previous VC is visible underneath. Just like the UIAlertViewController does, but with a custom view I've made.